# How to split file with marked blocks into many files in Python or Bash?

Tags: python, bash

i have the following in a file as input

```
begin mickey
<block of text>
end

begin mouse
<block of text>
end

begin miney
<block of text>
end
```

how can i parse the file to output:

```
file1: mickey.hostname (contain only mickey)
file2: mickey.cmds (contains the block of text)

file3: mouse.hostname
file4: mouse.cmds

file5: miney.hostname
file6: miney.cmds
```

thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. What does "contains the cat and locate lines" or "contains the tail and ls lines" mean?

Comment: @chris-sc, i updated the output.  it should contain the block of text only.

Comment: so `file1` should be an empty file?

Comment: @Trengot -- file1 should contain only mickey

Comment: How does your question relate to "multiple EOL"? The way you've phrased it, it sounds like you're just looking for someone to write the script for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`:

```
no=1
state=search
while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ "^start " ]] && [[ $state = search ]]; then
    name=${line#start }
    echo $name >file$no.txt
    no++
    state=text
    continue
  fi
  if [[ "$line" =~ "^end$" ]] && [[ $state = text]]; then
    no++
    state=search
    continue
  fi
  if [[ $state = text]]; then
    echo "$line" >>file$no.txt
    continue
  fi
done < orig.file
```

I do this from mind as morning exercise, it is your duty to check correctness.

Answer (score 0):

```
[it for it in map(lambda j: j.split('\n'),                   # 3. split each item on the newline to separate the name and block of text
              map(lambda l: l[6:],                           # 2. remove 'begin' from each item in the list
              map(lambda x: x.strip(), input.split('end')))) # 1. split all input on the word 'end', then remove whitespace at the ends of each item in the list
              if it[0]]                                      # 4. remove blank lines if any
```

produces the output

```
[['mickey', '<block of text>'],
 ['mouse', '<block of text>'],
 ['miney', '<block of text>']]
```

which should be easy enough to deal with from there

Comment: I don't like this answer, because it lacks any sort of explanation. It does not help the OP with his problem, but gives him more problems to understand this bit of code.

Comment: @BeowulfOF ok I add an explanation for each line hope that helps a bit